# is there a method to get an equivalent to defun-close for multi-line comment indenting in emacs?

Tags: emacs, coding-style

I've got to comply with a C style guide that says the following about multi-line comments:

Multi-line comments shall follow the following rules:

1. Comments starting with `//` shall not be used for multi-line comments.
2. The opening `/*` shall be alone on a line, or, if it is a doxygen multi-line comment, shall appear at the beginning of a line.
3. The closing `*/` shall be alone on a line.
4. The closing `*/` shall be aligned with the opening `/*`.
5. The body of the multi-line comment shall be indented one tab stop relative to the `/*` and `*/`.

Example:

```
/*
    Comment.
    More text.
*/
```

However, emacs doesn't seem to be able to treat the last comment line differently and indents it like this:

```
/*
    Comment.
    More text.
    */
```

Does anyone know how to convince emacs to treat the last comment line differently similar to the way closing braces in statements (e.g., `defun-close`, `block-close`) are handled differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: This is not a direct answer to your question, but should solve your requirements.

This may not be the prettiest solution, but it's working well.

If you change the offset for the syntactic symbol `c` (issuing <kbd>M-x</kbd> `c-set-offset`<kbd>RET</kbd>, with the cursor laying on a multiline comment) to `c-lineup-C-comments` you get something similar to what you want, but the comment text is indented by 1 character relative to the opening `*`.

Here is a modified version of `c-lineup-C-comments` that indents the comment text by `c-basic-offset` spaces.

```lisp
(defun my-c-lineup-C-comments (langelem)
  "Line up C block comment continuation lines.
Various heuristics are used to handle many of the common comment
styles.  Some examples:

/*          /**         /*         /* text      /*          /**
 * text      * text       text        text      ** text      ** text
 */          */         */         */           */           */

/*********************************************************************
 * text
 ********************************************************************/

/*********************************************************************
    Free form text comments:
 In comments with a long delimiter line at the start, the indentation
 is kept unchanged for lines that start with an empty comment line
 prefix.  The delimiter line is whatever matches the
 `comment-start-skip' regexp.
*********************************************************************/

The variable `c-comment-prefix-regexp' is used to recognize the
comment line prefix, e.g. the `*' that usually starts every line
inside a comment.

Works with: The `c' syntactic symbol."
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((here (point))
       (prefixlen (progn (back-to-indentation)
                 (if (looking-at c-current-comment-prefix)
                 (- (match-end 0) (point))
                   0)))
       (starterlen
        ;; Get the length of the comment starter, not including
        ;; the first '/'. We check if the comment prefix matched
        ;; on the current line matches the starter or if it
        ;; matches comment-start-skip, and choose whichever is
        ;; longest.
        (max (save-excursion
           (goto-char (1+ (c-langelem-pos langelem)))
           (if (and (match-string 0)
                (looking-at (regexp-quote (match-string 0))))
               (- (match-end 0) (match-beginning 0))
             0))
         (save-excursion
           (goto-char (c-langelem-pos langelem))
           (looking-at comment-start-skip)
           (- (or (match-end 1)
              (save-excursion
                (goto-char (match-end 0))
                (skip-chars-backward " \t")
                (point)))
              (point)
              1)))))
      (if (and (> starterlen 10) (zerop prefixlen))
      ;; The comment has a long starter and the line doesn't have
      ;; a nonempty comment prefix.  Treat it as free form text
      ;; and don't change the indentation.
      (vector (current-column))
    ;; Go back to the previous non-blank line, if any.
    (while
        (progn
          (forward-line -1)
          (back-to-indentation)
          (and (> (point) (c-langelem-pos langelem))
           (looking-at "[ \t]*$"))))
    ;; Is the starting line the first continuation line with content?
    (if (>= (c-langelem-pos langelem) (point))
        (if (zerop prefixlen)
        ;; No nonempty comment prefix. Align after comment
        ;; starter.
        (progn
          (looking-at comment-start-skip)
          (goto-char (match-end 0))
          ;; The following should not be necessary, since
          ;; comment-start-skip should match everything (i.e.
          ;; typically whitespace) that leads up to the text.
          ;;(if (looking-at "\\([ \t]+\\).+$")
          ;;    ;; Align with the text that hangs after the
          ;;    ;; comment starter.
          ;;    (goto-char (match-end 1)))
          ;;
          ;; EDITED HERE: this line was 
          ;; (vector (current column))
          (vector (+ (- c-basic-offset 1 starterlen) (current-column))))
          ;; How long is the comment starter?  if greater than the
          ;; length of the comment prefix, align left.  if less
          ;; than or equal, align right.  this should also pick up
          ;; Javadoc style comments.
          (if (> starterlen prefixlen)
          (progn
            (goto-char (c-langelem-pos langelem))
            (vector (+ 1 (current-column) )))
        (goto-char (+ (c-langelem-pos langelem) starterlen 1))
        (vector (- (current-column) prefixlen))))
      ;; We didn't start on the first non-blank continuation line.  If the
      ;; previous line has a nonempty comment prefix, align with it.
      ;; Otherwise, align with the previous nonempty line, but align the
      ;; comment ender with the starter.
      (when (or (not (looking-at c-current-comment-prefix))
            (eq (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)))
        (goto-char here)
        (back-to-indentation)
        (if (looking-at (concat "\\(" c-current-comment-prefix "\\)\\*/"))
        (goto-char (c-langelem-pos langelem))
          (while (and (zerop (forward-line -1))
              (looking-at "^[ \t]*$")))
          (back-to-indentation)
          (if (< (point) (c-langelem-pos langelem))
          ;; Align with the comment starter rather than
          ;; with the code before it.
          (goto-char (c-langelem-pos langelem)))))
      (vector (current-column)))))))
```

You can use it issuing <kbd>M-x</kbd> `c-set-offset`<kbd>RET</kbd>, with the cursor laying on a multiline comment.

**EDIT**

Following your comment, there are at least 2 ways to make it the default:

1. Add a hook to `c-mode-hook`:

   ```
   (defun my-c-mode-hook ()
     (c-set-offset 'c 'my-c-lineup-C-comments))
   (add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-hook)
   ```
2. Add a new C style using `c-add-style` and setting it as default customizing `c-default-style`:

   ```
   (c-add-style "mystyle"
     '("awk" ;; or whatever style you are currently using!
         (c-offsets-alist
            (c . my-c-lineup-C-comments)
         )
      )
   )
   ```

   To customize `c-default-style`, type

   <kbd>M-x</kbd>`customize-variable`<kbd>RET</kbd>`c-default-style`<kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Good enough! Thank you, sir.

Comment: Hmm... I can't seem figure out how to make your new function the default in .emacs. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working now. There was some stray commands for my c-mode setup in my .emacs file that needed to be cleaned up. Thanks again for your helpful reply.